# took a promotion then quit two weeks later, What to put on resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

I had a Shift manager position for about two years and then I was promoted to Assistant Manager. The problem is that when I was promoted to Assistant Manager, I quit after two weeks of having the position.

Should I put in my resume that I was Assistant Manager, when technically I wasn't, since I only had the position for two weeks? Or Should I put that I had a shift management position for 2.5 years in my resume and let them know at the same time that on the resume that I was promoted to Assistant Manager but quit after two weeks?

I'm also worried about what to write when applying for jobs online. It will ask what my last position was, do I put the Shift Manager position or put I was Assistant Manager?

Comment: Isn't assistant manager, lower than a manager?

Comment: well its actually shift manager then assistant manager then general manager. i was shift manager first then was promoted to assistant manager. i should have been clear, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem at all, just wondering is all.

Comment: In your shoes I would leave it off entirely.  Being in that role for such a short time may throw red flags for some employers and if it comes up in a background check you can say "I was still learning the ropes, it didn't seem right to list it as experience"

Comment: Thank you so much. That is actually a great explanation. How about when it ask what for what my last salary was. Should I put the salary I was earning as shift manager or assistant manager?

Comment: Don't answer the question - tell them what salary (range) you expect for the new position you're applying for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tough one. It largely depends on what happened to cause you to leave.

If you have a reasonable explanation for why you left so soon after getting promoted, I would put it on your resume. They chose to promote you. That says a lot about you, your work, your level of responsibility (which takes a hit from leaving so soon after the promotion unless you can explain it well).

I would be clear on the resume though.

`Feb 2014 - July 2016 Shift Manager`

`July 2016 - July 2016 Assistant Manager`

You wouldn't want to put `Feb 2014 - July 2016 Assistant Manager` or `Feb 2014 - July 2016 Shift Manager, Assistant Manager` as those would be misleading.

If your reason for leaving isn't sufficiently professional, leave the role off.

---

Edit: Upon clarification from the OP, Discussing the reasons for leaving likely takes the interview to a negative place. I would leave it off.

Comment: I actually didnt want the position. I had declined it so many times, but ony day, he announced that I was promoted to Assistant Manager that I decided no to speak up and just take the position. I quit after seeing the hours they were scheduling me. One week had me scheduled for 60+ hours and I knew that wasnt for me.

Comment: I probably wouldn't want to get into all of that in an interview. It takes it to a negative place. I would leave it off.

Comment: if they see it in my background check, how could I explain it without it negatively affecting me?

I just don't want to talk bad about the company. It was my first job and I learned a lot so I'm thankful. They just took advantage of me and didn't show any appreciation for everyones hard work and all employees had such low pay. It was just not a great workplace.

Comment: I think it's unlikely to come up in a background check. However, a good, positive response would be something like. 
"I knew that the company and role weren't a good fit for me, so I turned down the promotion several times. Eventually, they promoted me anyway just before I put in my notice."

Comment: What you said is exactly what happened! Thanks Chris, you have been such a great help. I feel better that my questions have been answered! thank you!

Comment: This is my last concern, if you could just help me a little bit more please.
How about when it ask for what my last salary was. Should I put the salary I was earning as shift manager or assistant manager?

Comment: Most places, you don't have to answer that question. Rather than ask "How much would you like to be paid?" folks often ask "How much did you get paid?". Because they're hoping to keep you underpaid. If they're expecting to pay $15/hour but you say you made $12, they may offer $13.50 to give you a nice perceived pay bump while saving some money. I wouldn't mention previous pay unless you're using it to negotiate up from a lower offer. Here, I would use your latest pay stub (likely with the Assistant Manager bump).

Comment: It was online applications that would ask that. Should I just leave them unanswered? It seems like its an option to leave it unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to one thing: **Do you want to be an assistant manager?** If you quit because it turns out being an assistant manager is not for you, I wouldn't include it. But if you want to be an assistant manager, by all means show them someone else already decided you were qualified for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should put your entire history including two weeks as assistant manager ... *and-d-d* that you should be prepared to respond to the inevitable "raised eyebrows." It is, of course, highly unusual for someone to quit their job, two weeks after receiving any promotion.

Also, I would recommend that you be sure to mention how many hours a week, what shifts, schedules, *etc,* you **are** (and, are not) willing to work. Obviously, your new schedule caused so much friction that you *walked out* instead of re-negotiating different hours. *(I'm not sure that this was such a good idea ...)* You need to be sure that you are looking at new jobs which call for an appropriate-to-you schedule.